# ARM; Performance Monitor Unit (PMU); Access th/ memory mapped registers;

Tags: arm, performancecounter, armv7, cortex-a

I'm trying to work with PMU module on ARM Cortex-A9.
PMU could be controlled over 'CP15 interface' or through memory-map registers. I need the latter one.

"ARM® Cortex®‑A9 MPCore Technical Reference Manual" states

> You can access the PMU counters, and their associated control registers through the internal CP15
>   interface, and through the APB, using the relevant offset when PADDRDBG[12]=1

Well, **how to read/write this `PADDRDBG` register?**

It seems that register is a part of 'CoreSight' module. Still could not find is it accessed th/ some `CPxx` interface or it's memory-mapped?

Any ideas? thanks.

PS: 'cp15' works fine, but I need memory access.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this is a signal on the core not something in address space possible the chip vendor has made a register for this so you have to look there, otherwise it is a compile time option (for the ARM core).  what chip is this?

Comment: a number of signals defined in the technical reference manual are logic signals, and of those some are compile time options...

Comment: it's 'Zynq-7000', dual-core ARM Cortex-A9 SoC.